# Firebase siginwithcustom token returns email as UID

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am using firebase in my react native application in which i am signing into the firebase using **signInWithCustomToken** in which i am passing the token that is received from my server.
Once the signInWithCustomToken is successful i checked the uid of that user. Instead of getting the uid i am getting the user email id like below

```
_auth: Auth {_app: App, _customUrlOrRegion: undefined, namespace: "auth", _user: User, _settings: null, …}
_user: {metadata: {…}, providerData: Array(0), phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, displayName: null, …}
displayName: (...)
email: (...)
emailVerified: (...)
isAnonymous: (...)
metadata: (...)
phoneNumber: (...)
photoURL: (...)
providerData: (...)
providerId: (...)
refreshToken: (...)
uid: "student@gmail.com"
```

The uid should be something like below **AbHH6vQvIDS8uPXw3ZPljQnWFRp3** but i am receiving the email in uid

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 2):

For custom tokens, the UID is whatever you specify in the token on your server in the call to `admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)` (or equivalent for your platform). So it seems like your server-side script is passing the email address instead of a generated/obfuscated ID.